# Render an element based on a given prop taking on appropriate element attributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to create a component that renders a specific HTML element based on properties given to it. In this case, I'd like to render a `div` if the component's `isDiv` property is true, and a `button` if it's false.

I also want to be able to provide my component with any of the element's attributes, which will be passed on down to the element itself.

Without TypeScript, I might write the component like so:

```jsx
const Button = ({ isDiv, elementProps, children }) => {
    return isDiv ? (
        <div {...elementProps} className="button">{children}</div>
    ) : (
        <button {...elementProps} className="button">{children}</button>
    );
};
```

To be used, for example, like:

```jsx
<Button type="submit" />
{/* <button class="button" type="button">...</button> */}
<Button isDiv />
{/* <div class="button">...</div> */}
```

My attempt now, using TypeScript (and a technique I've read refered to as a ["Discriminated Union"](https://medium.com/@azizhk/defining-interdependent-props-in-typescript-for-react-components-10f2688b0397)) is as follows:

```typescript
type DivProps = {
    isDiv: true;
    elementProps: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
};

type ButtonProps = {
    isDiv: false;
    elementProps: React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;
};

const Button: React.FC<DivProps | ButtonProps> = ({
    isDiv,
    elementProps,
    children,
}) => {
    return isDiv ? (
        <div {...elementProps} className="button">{children}</div>
    ) : (
        <button {...elementProps} className="button">{children}</button>
    );
};
```

Where I get errors due to `HTMLButtonElement` and `HTMLDivElement` not being compatible, ultimately:

> Property 'align' is missing in type 'HTMLButtonElement' but required in type 'HTMLDivElement'

How can I correctly implement this component using TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to help TS know about the relationship between `isDiv` and `elementProps` so it could narrow down the discriminated union.

this works:

```
const Button: React.FC<DivProps | ButtonProps> = ({
    children,
    ...props,

}) => {
    return props.isDiv ? (
        <div {...props.elementProps} className="button">{children}</div>
    ) : (
        <button {...props.elementProps} className="button">{children}</button>
    );
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get an error (`Type 'HTMLDivElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLButtonElement': disabled ...`) for `button`. `div` however, no longer has errors.

Comment: then i think there's something else to it. it should work :) 
here's a demo https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dubinsky-r9qzc?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: How odd. I can copy the exact code from the sandbox into my IDE and still get the error. Appreciate your help.

Comment: that is odd. i'm guessing you should enable `strict: true` in your `tsconfig.json`